# Zend Route Regex - Can't use the plus symbol in the URL

Tags: regex, zend-route

I have one question about regexp in zend_route.
I use this XML code to create route in ZendFramework:

```
<category>
    <type>Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex</type>
    <route>c-([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\+]+)</route>
    <defaults controller="category" action="index" seo_id=""/>
    <map seo_id="1" />
    <reverse>c-%s</reverse>
</category>
```

And I can go to the page http:://site.com/c-bla-bla_12
But I can't use plus symbol in the URL. For example, http:://site.com/c-bla+bla

How can I do this? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the URL is escaped before being passed to the regex. Try this :

```
<route>c-([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\+\s]+)</route>
```

Comment: I don't get error. Page opens, but I got seo_id='audio sd'. I want get seo_id with plus. How can I do this?

Comment: '+' is used to escape '<spaces>' inside an url. If you want '+' then replace spaces with '+'.